# Why is this broadcast operation slower than a nested for-loop

Tags: julia

I have a function that checks if every element in an array is greater than a lower bound and lesser than an upper bound.

In the following code, I'm curious to know why `bounds_error` (a nested for-loop) is faster than `bounds_error2` (vectorized, broadcast operation) and what can one do to make this function run faster.

```
using BenchmarkTools

function bounds_error(x, xl)
    num_x_rows = size(x,1)
    num_dim = size(xl, 1)
    for i in 1:num_x_rows
        for j in 1:num_dim
            if (x[i, j] < xl[j,1] || x[i,j] > xl[j,2])
                return true
            end
        end
    end
    return false
end

function bounds_error2(x, xl)
    for row in eachrow(x)
        xlt = transpose(xl)
        if any(row .< xlt[1, :]) == true || any(row .> xlt[2, :])
            return true
        end
    end
    return false
end

#number of rows in xl (or xlimits) will always be equal to number of columns in x

xl =  [     -5.0  5.0
            -5.0  5.0
            -5.0  5.0]

x = [1.0 2.0 3.0; 
     4.0 5.0 6.0]

@btime bounds_error(x, xl) #~20.645 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes); true

@btime bounds_error2(x, xl) #~347.870 ns (12 allocations: 704 bytes); true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason for this difference is memory allocations (`0` vs. `12` here).

```
#  20.645 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
# 347.870 ns (12 allocations: 704 bytes)
```

Currently, slices in Julia create a copy, so `xlt[1,:]` and `xlt[2,:]` allocates memory. To remedy this problem you should use `@views`. The second issue is the element-wise comparisons `row .< xlt[1,:]` and `row .> xlt[2,:]` create a temporary Boolean array. To avoid allocation of a temporary array, you should map `any(t->t[1]<t[2], zip(row,xl1))` so that the comparison is done one element at a time like a loop.

After applying these tips, the performance difference on my machine is now about `2ns` only, which accounts for the convenience of `eachrow`, `zip`, etc. instead of manual loops.

Note, for the first function, you can use `axes()` to loop over first or second dimension conveniently. And when benchmarking any Julia code with BenchmarkTools.jl, don't forget to interpolate (`$`) all variable names of a function to avoid working on global variables.

```
function bounds_error(x, xl)
    for i in axes(x,1)
        for j in axes(xl, 1)
            if (x[i, j] < xl[j,1] || x[i,j] > xl[j,2])
                return true
            end
        end
    end
    return false
end

@views function bounds_error2(x, xl)
    xl1, xl2 = xl[:,1], xl[:,2]
    for row in eachrow(x)
        if any(t->t[1]<t[2], zip(row,xl1)) || any(t->t[1]>t[2], zip(row,xl2))
            return true
        end
    end
    return false
end

# number of rows in xl (or xlimits) will always be equal to number of columns in x
xl = [-5.0  5.0
      -5.0  5.0
      -5.0  5.0]

x = [1.0 2.0 3.0; 
     4.0 5.0 6.0]

@btime bounds_error($x, $xl)  #  8.100 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
@btime bounds_error2($x, $xl) # 10.800 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

Comment: While allocations make the difference for these particular inputs, _in general_ the loop will be faster because it bails out immediately when it finds a value that is outside the limits, while the broadcasted version checks both entire arrays. This will be much more important than the allocations.

Comment: That's true, and is closely related to allocations as you said, `any` will wait for a whole row comparison to start its check.